# Route 53 mapping is not working with my domain in google

Tags: amazon-route53

I registered a domain in Google workspace. Let's say "amby.net". My email ID from google "info@amby.net". Now what happens is that if I use 'Default Name Servers' in google then my email ID works fine and I receive emails but if I switch them to "Custom Name Servers" then it stops working. What could be the reason ?